# Command not found on bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, startup, debian

I want to run a bash script to access two terminal tabs, each run `cd "folder"`, then `"npm run start"`, as below:

```
 #!/bin/bash
    sudo mysql -u root -h localhost 
    PATH=/var/lib/cloud9/autorun/loginbrillo
    tmux new-session -d -s session1 "cd $PATH/backend && npm run start" &
    tmux new-session -d -s sessionn1 "cd $PATH/frontend && npm run start" &
    chromium-browser  http://192.168.7.2:4001/
```

When I run it, I get :

```
tmux: command not found
npm: command not found
chromium-browser: command not found
```

How to fix it please ?

Comment: Don't use all-caps for your shell script variables - they are (informally) reserved for system environment variables. In this case, you've overwritten your shell's executable search path `PATH` - which is why no programs are being found. Just change the variable `PATH` to something else like `cloudpath`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The PATH variable is used to find all commands your script will use but rather than adding new directories to it you have overwritten it with a single directory, replace your second line with the following:

```
PATH=$PATH:/var/lib/cloud9/autorun/loginbrillo
```

PATH is a colon seperated list, this will get the current value of PATH, append a colon to it and add your directory to it

Comment: The OP appears to be using `PATH` as a working directory variable, not an executable search path

Comment: Great ! I get just : `chromium-browser: command not found`